# Pixelate and divide into parts image with c#

Tags: c#, pixel, divide

I want to pixelate image and divide image into parts that pixelated then I would like to take the approximate color of that divided part.

Imagine that fans are holding cartons and whole image is giving a shape and color of something ?

as in googled image : http://www.fenerbahcemaclari.com/images/tribun_resim.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Scale the image down to the number of pixels needed, then you can enlarge again. You can use the standard functionality of System.Drawing.Bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Pixelate image:
http://ericwillis.com/notes/2009/11/pixelate-an-image-with-csharp/

Comment: what about getting the main color of each pixels ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068373/how-to-calculate-the-average-rgb-color-values-of-a-bitmap