# Caculate color average returns "Attempt to divide by Zero"

Tags: c#, colors, pixel

I did try to use this code in my application from this problem:

[How to determine the background color of document when there are 3 options, using c# or imagemagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177499/how-to-determine-the-background-color-of-document-when-there-are-3-options-usin/6185448#6185448)

```
private System.Drawing.Color CalculateAverageColor(Bitmap bm)
{
    int width = bm.Width;
    int height = bm.Height;
    int red = 0;
    int green = 0;
    int blue = 0;
    int minDiversion = 15; // drop pixels that do not differ by at least minDiversion between color values (white, gray or black)
    int dropped = 0; // keep track of dropped pixels
    long[] totals = new long[] { 0, 0, 0 };
    int bppModifier = bm.PixelFormat == System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb ? 3 : 4; // cutting corners, will fail on anything else but 32 and 24 bit images

    BitmapData srcData = bm.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bm.PixelFormat);
    int stride = srcData.Stride;
    IntPtr Scan0 = srcData.Scan0;

    unsafe
    {
        byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                int idx = (y * stride) + x * bppModifier;
                red = p[idx + 2];
                green = p[idx + 1];
                blue = p[idx];
                if (Math.Abs(red - green) > minDiversion || Math.Abs(red - blue) > minDiversion || Math.Abs(green - blue) > minDiversion)
                {
                    totals[2] += red;
                    totals[1] += green;
                    totals[0] += blue;
                }
                else
                {
                    dropped++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int count = width * height - dropped;
    int avgR = (int)(totals[2] / count);
    int avgG = (int)(totals[1] / count);
    int avgB = (int)(totals[0] / count);

    return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(avgR, avgG, avgB);
}
```

The problem is when I add a bitmap, this happens:

[image]

Can someone help me figure out what exactly is happening?

Comment: It is always going inside else, so that value of dropped is width*height. So you have to debug why is it going inside else.

Comment: You probably want to check if count is zero and then just assign 0 to all the averages, assuming that all pixels should be "dropped" like if the bitmap is grayscale or black and white.  Or decide what the "average" color for grayscale or black and white should be.

Comment: Clearly `count` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

While there is an issue, the bigger question is how to determine the issue?

You're pointing out where it crashes, but why would it crash there?  It would only produce that error if `count` is zero.

```cs
int count = width * height - dropped;
```

Assuming the width and height are correct (and don't assume, put a breakpoint on this line and verify it!), this means `dropped` must be equal to `width * height`.

```cs
if (Math.Abs(red - green) > minDiversion || Math.Abs(red - blue) > minDiversion || Math.Abs(green - blue) > minDiversion)
...
else
{
    dropped++;
}
```

This code means that if the pixel is a grayscale color (or close to it), then it will increment `dropped`.  The idea is that it's only going to give you the average of the pixels with color, and avoid having grayscale pixels skew the results.

So, what's the solution?  There are two possible answers, only you can pick the right one for your problem set:

```cs
if (Math.Abs(red - green) > minDiversion || Math.Abs(red - blue) > minDiversion || Math.Abs(green - blue) > minDiversion)
```

You could just get rid of this check and always add something to the `totals` values.  This would give you a color in all cases, but how right that is depend on your needs.

```cs
int count = width * height - dropped;
if (count == 0)
{
    return Color.Black;
}
```

Or, you could check for the case where you can't find a color and just return a default response (or, maybe throw an Exception).

Depends on your needs.

Comment: I just figure out something, to trigger this method, I register it to an event where  bitmap changed, that bitmap will be put in the method and trigger it, but somehow when the bitmap changed, it adds the previous bitmap, not the current one, that why the bitmap is basically blank

Answer (score 0):

I should let everyone see this to understand the problem better
[image]