# Get average RGB values from picture displayed inside Image control in vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I want to get the average values of R, G and B from an image displayed inside an `Image` control. The source of this image is a frame captured from a webcam using [this dll](https://sites.google.com/site/webcamlibrarydotnet/wpf-with-vb-net-for-show-video-from-webcam-and-image-capturing).

Even though I found some functions that should be able to do this, they are either [for `C#` using pointers and unsafe code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068373/how-to-calculate-the-average-rgb-color-values-of-a-bitmap) or [for Windows Forms](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?776021-RESOLVED-Getting-Average-RGB-Color-Value-of-Entire-Screen), and I couldn't get them to work with the `Image` control.

How should I proceed to calculate that, or at least convert the `Image.Source` to `Bitmap` in order to use the function from the WinForms link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a straightforward, pure WPF solution, which directly accesses the pixel buffer of a BitmapSource. It works for the `Bgr24`, `Bgr32`, `Bgra32` and `Pbgra32` formats. In case of `Pbgra32` all alpha values should be 255, otherwise you may have to divide each pixel's (pre-multiplied) color values by `alpha / 255`.

```
public Color GetAverageColor(BitmapSource bitmap)
{
    var format = bitmap.Format;

    if (format != PixelFormats.Bgr24 &&
        format != PixelFormats.Bgr32 &&
        format != PixelFormats.Bgra32 &&
        format != PixelFormats.Pbgra32)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("BitmapSource must have Bgr24, Bgr32, Bgra32 or Pbgra32 format");
    }

    var width = bitmap.PixelWidth;
    var height = bitmap.PixelHeight;
    var numPixels = width * height;
    var bytesPerPixel = format.BitsPerPixel / 8;
    var pixelBuffer = new byte[numPixels * bytesPerPixel];

    bitmap.CopyPixels(pixelBuffer, width * bytesPerPixel, 0);

    long blue = 0;
    long green = 0;
    long red = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < pixelBuffer.Length; i += bytesPerPixel)
    {
        blue += pixelBuffer[i];
        green += pixelBuffer[i + 1];
        red += pixelBuffer[i + 2];
    }

    return Color.FromRgb((byte)(red / numPixels), (byte)(green / numPixels), (byte)(blue / numPixels));
}
```

As the Image control's `Source` property is of type `ImageSource`, you have to cast it to `BitmapSource` before passing it to the method:

```
var bitmap = (BitmapSource)image.Source; 
var color = GetAverageColor(bitmap);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly after I translated it to VB (not a problem with online tools), thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED to support WPF image control (still requires reference to System.Drawing).**

```
Public Function GetWPFImageAverageRGB(wpfImage As System.Windows.Controls.Image) As System.Drawing.Color
    Using ms = New IO.MemoryStream()
        Dim encoder = New JpegBitmapEncoder()
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(CType(wpfImage.Source, BitmapImage)))
        encoder.Save(ms)

        Using bmp = CType(System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(ms), System.Drawing.Bitmap)
            Dim reds As Long
            Dim greens As Long
            Dim blues As Long

            For x = 0 To bmp.Width - 1
                For y = 0 To bmp.Height - 1
                    With bmp.GetPixel(x, y)
                        reds += .R
                        greens += .G
                        blues += .B
                    End With
                Next
            Next

            Dim count = bmp.Height * bmp.Width

            Return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CInt(reds / count), CInt(greens / count), CInt(blues / count))
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Usage:

```
With GetWPFImageAverageRGB(image) 'image is a System.Windows.Controls.image
   Console.WriteLine("Average: R={0}, G={1}, B={2}", .R, .G, .B)
   Console.ReadKey()
End With
```

Comment: @OneFineDay, yes it would.

Comment: Thanks Craig. I was able to get the RGB averages from a file, but still can't find a way to use the Source of a Image control instead. Any tips on that? Also, like @OneFineDay mentioned, this double loop is kinda slow, would the conversion to `lockbits` bit too complicated?

Comment: One way or the other you will be traversing all the bytes, whether in a double loop or through a byte array. `.GetPixel` is where any adverse cost is incurred (it's still pretty zippy though). You have a WPF Image element? The function just accepts an Image object so it could be straight from your element instead of using `Drawing.Image.FromFile()` And yeah I will post a LockBits implementation as well.

Comment: Sorry for my insistence, but if I simply try `GetImageAverageRGB(imgCapture)` (`imgCapture` is the name of the Image object) I get `Value of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' cannot be converted to 'System.Drawing.Image'`.

Comment: @Molx sorry about that! See edits. I tried this from a WPF window with an image control and a loaded .PNG. If anyone has an easier, less roundabout way to do this, I'd love to know as well.

Comment: Still no go, unfortunately. I was able to compile and run, but I get an error once I try to get the Avg RGBs on the `Ctype` line: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Interop.InteropBitmap' to type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage'.` I get a similar error from a clear project with a image (bmp and png) imported into an Image object.